# select all from where there are multiple values for a column

Tags: mysql, database

I have a db of personnel which every person can have one or multiple countries. The countries can be added from a multiple choice drop down to db.
A person could be like this

```
name   country   
john   USA, UK, Poland   
joe    USA  
Jack   Germany
```

user can filter people by changing the value of <%= country %>
I am trying to filter people based on user's choice. I am using this query

```
 SELECT *
FROM `personnel`
WHERE <%= country %> LIKE `country`
ORDER BY `industry` ASC, `name` ASC
```

the problem is this select filters only rows(people) with single country, and it doesn't show people who has more that one country.
I tried to use = instead of LIKE but that one didn't work also

Comment: Fix you data structure, so you have a table called `PersonnelCountry`, with one row per person and country.

Comment: the db is  personnel, my bad. yes every person has one row and in country column they can have either one or multiple countries

Comment: But the best solution would be to normalise your table structure as @GordonLinoff has suggested.

Comment: @Shadow, the find_in_set was the answer tnx, 
this fixed my problem
find_in_set(<%= country %>, `country`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **%** in **LIKE** sentence. `LIKE '%country%'`
**%** allows search in all the string, no matter what has after and before.
If you LIKE 'country' it show only the person with single country.

Cheers